# Finding subgroups via modulo arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the following numbers : $1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19$. In terms of modulo $20$ how many subgroups are there? For example, $3(7) = 21 = 1$ mod $20$.

In particular I want to find the generators.

Comment: There are no generators; $3^4=81\equiv 1 \mod 20, 7^4=2401 \equiv 1 \mod 20, 9^2=81\equiv 1 \mod 20, 11^2=121\equiv 1 \mod 20, 13^4=28561\equiv 1\mod 20, 17^2\equiv 83521, 19^2=361\equiv 1 \mod 20$.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing besides getting $1$ mod $20$ with all of the numbers. I know one subgroup is $<3>$. I am not sure how to get the other $4$.

Comment: I am showing that there are no (single) generators for the group by showing that none of them have order equal to 8; in order for a single element to be a generator, it must have the order of the group.  As for finding non-singleton sets that generate the group, I am calculating the remaining subgroups.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you are saying. Then yes, what you put makes sense ;). I am curious what the other subgroups are. I am interested to see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting this question as "What is the structure of the group of numbers coprime to 20 under multiplication modulo 20?".

Here is the multiplication table:

```
 1  3  9  7 11 13 19 17
 3  9  7  1 13 19 17 11
 9  7  1  3 19 17 11 13
 7  1  3  9 17 11 13 19
11 13 19 17  1  3  9  7
13 19 17 11  3  9  7  1
19 17 11 13  9  7  1  3
17 11 13 19  7  1  3  9
```

So it appears to be $C_4 \times C_2$.

The $C_4$ subgroup is generated by $3$ and the $C_2$ subgroup is generated by $11$. Other choices are also possible.

Edit: You also asked what the subgroups are. There is one subgroup with no generators:

```
1
```

There are five subgroups with one generator:

```
1 3 9 7
1 9
1 11
1 13 9 17
1 19
```

There is one subgroup with two generators (other than the whole group):

```
1 9 11 19
```

Comment: This is written very nicely. Thank you. I like all of these tables :p

Comment: How different are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^\ast$ then? I assume they are quite different.

Comment: I don't know what $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^*$ means, sorry. Please can you give me its name in English, so that I can google it?

Comment: @user114030 $\mathbb Z_{20}^*$ *is* the group $\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$ in this question.

Comment: @apt1002 For a ring $R$, the group of units under multiplication is denoted by $R^*$.

Comment: Oh okay. So, Arthur the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^\ast$ are in fact the ones Hayden listed then?